# Bulletproof Button on Outlook Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: html, email, button, outlook

I'm writing some code for an email; unfortunately, I work for a public university with a proprietary email environment (and no money for Litmus), so I've run into a problem I just can't seem to fix.

I've used some code for a bulletproof button that looks great everywhere except for in Outlook.

It's showing up like this when viewed using an Outlook desktop client:

[Bulletproof Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E1SW.jpg)

[Here's a JS Fiddle of my code.](https://jsfiddle.net/modern_ism/d018wn6z/1/)

```html
<tr>
  <!-- Bulletproof Button -->
  <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
<tr>
<td style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#001e62f;border: 2px solid #001e62;" align="center" valign="middle">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td width="18" height="40" style="display:none;" class="mso-only">&nbsp;</td><td>
<![endif]-->
<a href="https://advance.uic.edu/" target="_blank" style="display:block;background-color:#001e62;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:17px;border-top:12px solid #001e62;border-bottom:12px solid #001e62;border-left:25px solid #001e62;border-right:25px solid #001e62;">GIVE NOW</a>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td><td width="18" style="display:none;" class="mso-only">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Bulletproof Button -->
                  </tr>
```

Does anyone know how this could be fixed for Outlook?

Comment: which outlook version you are checking. i checked mobile outlook and mac outlook app its looks good.

Comment: do correction to `td` style `background-color: #001e62f;` and try out

Comment: @aviboy2006 It's showing up like this on 2016 Outlooks for PCs ONLY...which seems niche enough to ignore, but unfortunately that's what half of the school I work at is using.